# Projetos MVC5 separados do .Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Gostaria de criar uma solução onde eu tenho 3 projetos obedecendo a seguinte estrutura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A index do meu site será responsável pelo cadastramento do usuário para que ele tenha acesso aos outros sistemas (WebApp1 e WebApp2).
Porém quando executo o cadastramento e login em Identity e navego até uma página que requer autorização em WebApp1/Confidencial, a aplicação não está considerando a sessão que já está iniciada e me leva a té o cadastro de usuário.

O objetivo é separar minhas aplicações da camada do Identity. Isso facilitaria o gerenciamento dos projetos e outros que poderão surgir.

Comment: No momento não consigo te responder com muitos detalhes, mas me parece que o que você está procurando é uma implementação de "Single Sign-On" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). Tenta procurar com este termo, acho que vais achar mais informações.

Comment: Seria algo parecido com o SSO, mas eu quero poder utilizar o Google, Facebook,... como logins e também um cadastro próprio, um projeto MVC padrão com authenticação. O WebApp1 e WebApp2 (projetos MVC Empty) estão no mesmo domínio e dentro do aplicativo (no IIS) de Identity. O problema é que o usuário já logado (Identity) não está sendo levado em conta dentro das outras aplicações mesmo estando no mesmo domínio. Deve ser uma necessidade muito básica. Eu não gostaria mas estou pensando em utilizar Areas em Identity e ali dentro eu crio WebApp1 e WebApp2.